# using mule read txt file from website

Tags: mule

I am very new to mule. I am trying to read a http link, which outputs txt file.
I want to call this link in mule, read text and insert data in to database.

Can any one suggest me how to read txt file in mule when file is coming from http.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider there is a HTTP url `localhost:8081/service` which will provide a text output while calling it.
So, to call it from Mule flow, you need to configure HTTP outbound or HTTP request component which is used to call external url.
So, you need to configure it in following way :-
If you are using **Mule 3.5** or earlier, you need outbound endpoint :-

```
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="localhost:8081/service" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
```

If you are using **Mule 3.6** or later version, you need Http request component :-

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081"  doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
```

And in **Mule** **flow** :-

```
<http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/service" method="GET" doc:name="Call external service" />
```

Reference :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/HTTP+Request+Connector

After calling the external url from Mule flow, you will be getting the text as payload, which you can insert into database using your SQL query

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Mule HTTP Endpoint](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Endpoint+Reference).